# How to add a custom object to a Rails model in a migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails model called service_request that I want to add a request_form object to.  I have defined the RequestForm class in my models directory, though it is only for use as a "has-A/helper" object to the ServiceRequest class, not actually part of the database.  I am trying to add a migration as follows:

```
rails generate migration AddRequestFormToServiceRequest request_form:request_form
```

But I get the top-level error:

```
PG::UndefinedObject: ERROR:  type "request_form" does not exist
```

Do i have to define this class somewhere specific for this to work?

Thanks

Comment: Slightly confused here as to what you're actually wanting to do here. Migrations are used for modifying the database table underlying a model, and are limited to a particular set of types, corresponding to the database data types -- you can't create your own custom ones. If you're trying to set up an association (like a `has_one`/`belongs_to` association), you'd add a reference to the database, but I'm not even certain that's what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails migrations are used to create and modify the structure of the database.

If you have a existing model ServiceRequest and you want to relate a RequestForm to it you should use the model generator, not the migration generator.

```
rails g model RequestForm title:string content:text service_request_id:integer
```

this creates a model `RequestForm` and a database table `request_forms` with a foreign key reference to the related service_request

You have to also add the relation in the models like:

```
class ServiceRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :request_forms
end

class RequestForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_request
end
```

The PG error you get, is because you are trying to assign request_form to a custom type that doesn't exist in the Postgres database.

Comment: Thank you. What i was doing was a bit off base, and I've got it working now thanks to this.

Answer (score 0):

This reads like a case where the model generator syntax may not capture what you want.  Try:

```
rails generate migration AddRequestFormToServiceRequest
```

and then open up the AddRequestFormToServiceRequest migration file it creates in an editor and add the columns you need adding by hand.